# Array's list declare winners and times

Tags: python, arrays, list

User input of 8 race times for two different teams Chevy and Ford.
Declare the winner of each race.
Show the time they won by in seconds.
Declare the the team who won the most.

I have created the two team lists, with their times.
The problem I am having is how to pull each time from its place in the list and declare that individual the winner. My code isn't functioning properly and I think it has to do with how my loop is set up. I also don't want to print the strings of the the race times but I don't know how to get my calculations for who won to work without having that in the code.
I am just learning how to code so bear with me please.
I will put notes in my code to indicate what I am talking about to help create a better picture.

```
#Team Chevy
Chevy = [0.0] * 8
for i in range(8):
    Chevy[i] = float(input("Enter Chevy race time's: "))
    i = i + 1
for i in range(0,8):
    print("Chevy", str(i+1) + ": ", Chevy[i]) # I want to be able to remove the print function so I don't have the times showing up with the input and the print. But it messes up my winner determination when I remove it.

#Team Ford   
Ford = [0.0] * 8
for j in range(8):
    Ford[j] = float(input("Enter Ford race time's: "))
    j = j + 1
for j in range(0,8):
    print("Ford", str(j+1) + ": ", Ford[j])

#Determine winner    
if Chevy[0] > Ford[0]:
    winner = Chevy[0] - Ford[0]
    print("Ford wins by",winner,"sec")
elif Ford[0] < Chevy[0]:
    winner = Chevy[0] - Ford[0]
    print("Chevy wins by",winner,"sec")
```

Results

```
Enter Chevy race time's: 1
Enter Chevy race time's: 2
Enter Chevy race time's: 3
Enter Chevy race time's: 4
Enter Chevy race time's: 5
Enter Chevy race time's: 6
Enter Chevy race time's: 7
Enter Chevy race time's: 8
Chevy 1:  1.0
Chevy 2:  2.0
Chevy 3:  3.0
Chevy 4:  4.0
Chevy 5:  5.0
Chevy 6:  6.0
Chevy 7:  7.0
Chevy 8:  8.0

Enter Ford race time's: 9
Enter Ford race time's: 8
Enter Ford race time's: 7
Enter Ford race time's: 6
Enter Ford race time's: 5
Enter Ford race time's: 4
Enter Ford race time's: 3
Enter Ford race time's: 2
Ford 1:  9.0
Ford 2:  8.0
Ford 3:  7.0
Ford 4:  6.0
Ford 5:  5.0
Ford 6:  4.0
Ford 7:  3.0
Ford 8:  2.0

Chevy wins by 8.0 sec
```

Only display input times.
Display winners of each race( race 1 is Chevy[0] vs Ford[0]).
Declare winners of each race or a tie.
Declare team with the most wins.

Answer (score 0):

Python offers several ways to built list, each has it's advantages try to study them all. The code follows with three ways of doing so. Notice that you dont always need a index "i's" to go through a list.

```
R = int(input("Enter the number of races: "))
#Team Chevy
Chevy = []
for c in range(R):
    Chevy.append(float(input("Enter Chevy race {} time's: ".format((c+1)))))
#
#Team Ford   
Ford = [0.0] * R
for f, F in enumerate(Ford, start=1):
    Ford[f-1] = float(input("Enter Ford race {} time's: ".format(f)))
#
#Determine winner    
k = 1
for Chevy, Ford in zip(Chevy, Ford):
    delta_time = Chevy - Ford
    if delta_time < 0 :
        print("Chevy wins race {} by {} s.".format(k, (-delta_time)))
    if delta_time > 0 :
        print("Ford wins race {} by {} s.".format(k, delta_time))
    if delta_time == 0 :
        print("The race {} was a Draw with the time of {} s.".format(k, Chevy))
    k += 1
#
```

Comment: Thanks. Yea I was looking into zip but didn’t quite understand it yet. I’ll try this out and play with it to better understand them.

Comment: How do I divide up the results of the winners into a winning team.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
print ('Welcome to the Chevy vs. Ford Drag Races!')
ford_time = []
chevy_time = []
ford_wins = 0
chevy_wins = 0
print("---Input Chevy Times---")
for i in range(1,9):
    chevy_time.append(float(input("Enter time for Chevy Car "+str(i)+": ")))
print("\n---Input Ford Times---")
for i in range(1,9):
    ford_time.append(float(input("Enter time for Ford Car "+str(i)+": ")))
print("\nAnd the winners are:\n")
for i in range(0,8):
    if ford_time[i] > chevy_time[i]:
        difference = ford_time[i] - chevy_time[i]
        chevy_wins = chevy_wins+1
        print("Chevy by {0:.2f} sec".format(difference))
    elif ford_time[i] < chevy_time[i]:
        difference = chevy_time[i] - ford_time[i]
        ford_wins = ford_wins+1
        print("Ford by {0:.2f} sec".format(difference))
    else:
        print("Tie!")
if ford_wins > chevy_wins:
    print("\nAnd the winning team is: F O R D !")
elif ford_wins < chevy_wins:
    print("\nAnd the winning team is: C H E V Y !")
else:
    print("It's a T I E !")
```